# Create ASP Button Dynamically with Arguements Passed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to create a set of ASP C# buttons dynamically, which all call the same event on click, which I am able to implement fine like so....

```
Button updateClientPriceButton = new Button();
updateClientPriceButton.ID = "bttnUpdatePrice_" + row["company_name"].ToString();
updateClientPriceButton.Text = "Update";
updateClientPriceButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(updateClientPriceButton_Click);
```

With...

```
protected void updateClientPriceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But how do I send an arugment in the type of string to this function also? I have tried..

```
updateClientPriceButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(updateClientPriceButton_Click(object, EventArgs, "test_value"));
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the `Click` event. However Button has a `Command` event for this purpose:

```
updateClientPriceButton.Command += new System.EventHandler(updateClientPriceButton_Command);
updateClientPriceButton.CommandName = "SomeName";
updateClientPriceButton.CommandArgument = "test_value";
```

And the handler should look like this:

```
protected void updateClientPriceButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with e.CommandName and e.CommandArgument
}
```

The other way is to create you own control inheriting from `Button` with special event based on `Button.Click` and with special arguments. But having `Command` in place this seems to be an overhead here.